# Python prints additional characters when redirecting the print command

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, printing

I have a strange problem. I want to display the command output and also redirect it to a tkinter window and save the displayed text to a .txt file.
The "message" is the string from inside the print commands in my code and gets redirected to the gui_redirector.

```
    def gui_redirector(self, std_print):
        def gui_addition(message):
            message = "test" + "__" + message
            add_to_eternal_log(message)
            self.textbox_output.insert(tk.END, message)
            self.textbox_output.see(tk.END)
            # raise ValueError(message)  As an error the output works as expected
            return std_print(message)
        return gui_addition

    sys.stdout.write = self.gui_redirector(sys.stdout.write)

    print("Hello")
```

In the different outputs I then get the following outputs (with message being "Hello" for example):

The tkinter window, the textfile and the command window all contain

`test__Hellotest__`

Only when I enable the forced error message, it correctly displays

`test__Hello`

How does the "test__" part of the message get copied to the end of the string?
I suspected it has something to do with hidden newline characters at the end of print statements but changing the command to `print("Hello", end="")` didn't change anything.

I'm really out of ideas here. Does someone know how this happens and to avoid it?

Some bonus weirdness: If I try to slice off some characters from the end by doing `self.textbox_output.insert(tk.END, message[:-3])` the output changes to `test__Hetest` which means it deletes part of the intended message and part of the additional "test__".

Comment: You can temporarily use `message = "test" + "__" + repr(message)` to find out what exactly "message" contains.

Comment: @MichaelButscher It actually shows the hidden newline character!
The result is `test__'Hello'test__'\n'`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher If Iinclude the `end=""` at the end of the print command it still displays `test__'Hello'test__''`. Is there a way to get rid of these trailing characters completely? Simply adding `.strip()` to message wont so the trick.

Comment: As they are generated by "print" (by its code) I think you can only modify "gui_addition" to ignore an empty message or handle a message differently if it only contains a newline.

Comment: Only prepend `"test__"` when `message.strip() != ""`.

Comment: I tried many different ways to delete any hidden newline characters, but none worked.
What ultimately worked was an if clause in front of the line to add the date.
It now says `if message != ("" or "\n"): message = "test" + "__" + message`
Somehow a hidden newline created the second "test__" part but couldn't be deleted.
Now the second line (which is empty anyway) doesn't get forwarded what solves the problem.